# winui3 command line arguments not working

Tags: command-line-arguments, winui-3

I am working on a winui3 (packaged) project.

**I am trying to pass arguments while starting a new process**
But for some reason, either the process starting method or arguments reading method isn't working.

These are the multiple ways I already tried.

**To start the process**

```
Process.Start(Environment.ProcessPath, StartupMethod.UPLOAD);
```

or

```
ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new()
{
    FileName = Environment.ProcessPath,
    Arguments = StartupMethod.UPLOAD
};

Process.Start(processStartInfo);
```

**To read the arguments**

```
string[] arguments = args.Arguments.Split(" ", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

or

```
string[] arguments = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
```

But none of the combinations seems to be working.

*Also, I tried to run the **Environment.ProcessPath** manually, but the .exe file isn't running for some reason.*

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code, and it work for me. Could you reproduce the same problem in a new blank winui3?

Comment: Environment.GetCommandLineArgs(); worked for me, I may have overlooked due to the filename it returns at index 0. Thanks anyway...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me.

**Start the process**

```
Process P = new();
P.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
P.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
P.StartInfo.FileName = Environment.ProcessPath;
P.StartInfo.Arguments = "This is a Test"; 
P.Start();
```

**Read the arguments in App.xaml.cs**

```
protected override void OnLaunched(Microsoft.UI.Xaml.LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    m_window = new MainWindow();
    m_window.Activate();

    string[] arguments = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
    if (arguments.Length > 1)
    {
        //do something
    }
            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**To start the process**

```
Process.Start(Environment.ProcessPath, "Arguments");
```

**To read the arguments**

```
string[] arguments = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
```

*The `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()` return filename at the first position, so might want to skip that*